# Trouble setting request specific timeout in Elasticsearch DSL

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm trying to set a `timeout` for a specific request using `elasticsearch_dsl`. I've tried the following:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search, F

...

def do_stuff(self, ids):
    client = Elasticsearch(['localhost'], timeout=30)
    s = Search(using=client,
               index= 'my_index',
               doc_type=['my_type'])
    s = s[0:100]
    f = F('terms', my_field=list(ids))
    s.filter(f)

    response = s.execute()
    return response.hits.hits
```

Notes:

- When I change the `doc_type` to a type containing a million entities, the query runs fine.
- When I point the `doc_type` to a few billion entities, I get a timeout error showing the default timeout of 10 seconds.

From the `elasticsearch_dsl` [docs](http://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#default-connection) I even tried setting the default connection timeout:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search, F
from elasticsearch_dsl import connections

connections.connections.create_connection(hosts=['localhost'], timeout=30)
```

I still received the 10 second timeout error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So for some reason adding the parameter via `.params()` seems to do the trick:

```
s = Search(using=client,
           index= 'my_index',
           doc_type=['my_type'])
    .params(request_timeout=30)
```

The really interesting part is that the query now takes less than a second to run and the index is only on a single node.

Comment: The parameter **timeout=30** gives the following error: ```TransportError(400, 'parse_exception', 'Failed to parse setting [timeout] with value [30] as a time value: unit is missing or unrecognized')```. You should use **request_timeout=30** instead.

Comment: @coda, are you sure this is the case? maybe it is just because it is somehow cached. Did you repeat your search, or you search for something different?